# Why is this OkHttp POST that supports a BODY missing its Content-Type Header?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2, okhttp

I saw that [`Content-Type` header is removed for methods that don't support a `Body`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1945#issuecomment-235494220), but that isn't my case. I've also confirmed my `User-Agent` header is successfully set.

This can be done statically via the interface with the endpoint's definition but I'd favor a global [`Interceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#network-interceptors) over annotating all my methods.

```
// Api.kt
@POST("authenticated_users")
fun postUser(
    @Body newUser: NewUser
): Observable<AuthUser>

class UserRepo @Inject constructor(private val api: Api) {
    fun postUser(newUser: NewUser) = api.postUser(newUser)
}

// NetModule.kt
@Provides @Singleton
fun providesOkHttpClient(cache: Cache, app: Application): OkHttpClient {
    val timeoutInSeconds = 90.toLong()
    val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cache(cache)
        .addInterceptor(MyInterceptor(app))
        .connectTimeout(timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    when {
        BuildConfig.DEBUG -> {
            val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS
            }

            with(builder) {
                addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())
            }
        }
    }

    return builder.build()
}

@Provides @Singleton
fun providesMoshi(): Moshi {
    val jsonApiAdapterFactory = ResourceAdapterFactory.builder()
        .add(TermsConditions::class.java)
        .add(AuthUser::class.java)
        .add(Unknown::class.java)
        .build()

    val builder = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(jsonApiAdapterFactory)
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    return builder.build()
}

@Provides @Singleton
fun providesRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, moshi: Moshi): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        // .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(JsonApiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}

// MyInterceptor.kt
class MyInterceptor @Inject constructor(private val app: Application) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val initialRequest = chain.request()
        val finalRequest = setHeaders(initialRequest)
        return chain.proceed(finalRequest)
    }

    private fun setHeaders(initialRequest: Request): Request {
        return initialRequest.newBuilder()
            // .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
            .header("User-Agent", "MyApp v${BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME}")
            .build()
    }
}

// MyViewModel.kt
fun createUser() {
    userObserver = object : DisposableObserver<AuthUser>() {
        override fun onNext(authUser: AuthUser) {
            statusData.postValue(true)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            Timber.w(e.localizedMessage)
            error.postValue(e.localizedMessage)
        }

        override fun onComplete() {
            // no-op
        }
    }

    userRepo.postUser(newUser)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(userObserver)
}

// log1.txt Retrofit with ScalarsConverterFactory
2018-04-18 15:20:35.772 16491-17436/com.es0329.myapp D/OkHttp: --> POST https://api.es0329.com/v5/authenticated_users
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 259
    User-Agent: MyApp v1.5.1
    --> END POST
2018-04-18 15:20:36.278 16491-17436/com.es0329.myapp D/OkHttp: <-- 500 https://api.es0329.com/v5/authenticated_users (505ms)

// log2.txt Retrofit without ScalarsConverterFactory
2018-04-18 18:25:45.742 5017-6325/com.es0329.myapp D/OkHttp: --> POST https://api.es0329.com/v5/authenticated_users
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 311
    User-Agent: MyApp v1.5.1
    --> END POST
2018-04-18 18:25:45.868 5017-6325/com.es0329.myapp D/OkHttp: <-- 500 https://api.es0329.com/v5/authenticated_users (125ms)

// log3.txt after modifying JsonApiConverterFactory's `MediaType`
2018-04-18 20:35:47.322 19368-19931/com.es0329.myapp D/OkHttp: --> POST https://api.es0329.com/v5/authenticated_users
    Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
    Content-Length: 268
    User-Agent: MyApp v1.5.1
    --> END POST
2018-04-18 20:35:49.058 19368-19931/com.es0329.myapp D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://api.es0329.com/v5/authenticated_users (1735ms)
```

Comment: post the relevant code here

Comment: updated @TimCastelijns

Comment: This has nothing to do with OkHttp, that's just hauling bytes over network. Retrofit is in charge of *what* gets transmitted. In your question you don't mention your Retrofit configuration, can you add that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is it not working

Retrofit is in charge of setting appropriate content type and length based on registered converters and what you provide to your `@Body` parameter.

In greater detail: A Retrofit converter is responsible for transforming the type of your `@Body` to `okhttp3.RequestBody` which holds your content bytes, content length, and content type. Similarly on the way back. You supply content, `ResponseBody` handles details like HTTP headers.

**You can't manually override these headers.**

As you can see in the log, your string body gets successfully transmitted as `text/plain`.

```
--> POST https://api.es0329.com/v5/authenticated_users
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 259
User-Agent: MyApp v1.5.1
--> END POST
```

That leads me to believe you have a registered converter and it's the [scalar converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars), which states:

> A Converter which supports converting strings and both primitives and their boxed types to `text/plain` bodies.

#### What to to instead

All of the ready-made converters (Moshi, Gson, Jackson) are built to convert POJOs to `application/json`. This is a typical case and you should use one of these if you can. [Explore source code here.](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters)

There are plenty of tutorials online for this case.

#### Rocky alternative

If for some reason you want/need to continue your current direction, that is prepare a JSON string manually and send that as `application/vnd.api+json`, you'll need a custom converter.

The aforementioned [scalar converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/scalars) already knows how to transform strings, so copy it into your project and adapt it to your needs (change the mime type). It's just a set of three classes:

- convertor factory
- request body convertor (transforms the `@Body` to `okhttp3.RequestBody`)
- repsonse body convertor (transforms the `okhttp3.ResponseBody` to return value)

Comment: That's good info @eugen-pechanec! I removed the `ScalarsConverterFactory` and shared updated logs. The `Content-Type` header key is now present but its value isn't exactly what server expects, so status remains `500`.

Comment: You used a Moshi converter, right? It's trying to send your String as JSON. The converter added double quotes to start and end. Either [send a POJO using a Moshi converter](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body) or keep sending String but you have to write your own converter.

Comment: **200!!**

#1. In refactoring I overlooked logic sending `String` payloads. Correcting those places didn't solve it.
#2. This is a http://jsonapi.org/ service. I have a spec-compliant converter ahead of `MoshiConverterFactory`, as Retrofit prescribes.
I found the JsonApi converter's `MediaType` was `"application/json; charset=UTF-8"`, properly setting it was the last fix.
Now JsonApi converter just handles the request; even making it unnecessary to use add `Content-Type` via `Interceptor`. It just works.

Fun ;D Thanks for working through it with me!